# Laravel Model Bulk Update - Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, null given

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-7

I'm trying to bulk update the date of a model in Laravel via an Ajax request from my Vue component. I have the following as my code but I'm not sure where the error is, I've also tested this by using Postman which I will provide the results for.

Vue component script tag

```
export default {
  props: ['data'],
  data() {
    return {
      last: null
    }
  },
  methods:{
    ...
    update(){
      console.log(this.data);
      console.log(this.last);
      axios.put('/api/maintain/bulk',
      {
        params: {
          'ids': this.data,
          'date': this.last.toString()
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }, (xhr) => {
        console.log(xhr);
      });
     }
  },
  ...
}
```

`data` is passed from a parent component that when logged returns `[328, 346, __ob__: Observer]`

`last` is set by an input of type date
routes/api.php

```
...
Route::put('/maintain/bulk', 'MaintenanceController@bulkupdate');
...
```

MaintenanceController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Maintain;

class MaintenanceController extends Controller
{
  ...
  public function bulkupdate(Request $request){
    Maintain::whereIn('id', $request->input('ids'))->update(['start' => $request->input('date')]);
  }
}
```

Postman API Call

```
PUT | http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/maintain/bulk`
body:
{
    "ids": [328, 346],
    "date": 2020-10-29
}
```

Response - Error is also displayed in the Laravel log file

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\Users\adam\LaravelProjects\EMG-AIM-Dev\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php on line 918 in file C:\Users\adam\LaravelProjects\EMG-AIM-Dev\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php on line 2954
```

-EDIT-

I have realised what is wrong with the request but I'm still unsure of how to fix it, I've amended the Postman call to show the current issue, I've figured this is due to the fact that passing a date from a DOM input doesn't seem to register it as a string.

The PUT is successful when the date is added to the request as a string (`"2020-10-29"`) but at the moment the date is not being passed as a string despite the fact that when I send the parameters via the Ajax request I use the `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that changing the code to the following solved the issue

Vue Component

```
axios.put('/api/maintain/bulk', {
          'ids': this.data,
          'date': this.last
        })...
```

Maintenance Controller

```
public function bulkupdate(Request $request){
    Maintain::whereIn('id', $request->ids)->update(['start' => $request->date]);
}
```